# Can`t load jQuery library

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to load jQuery library following videos but it does not work. When I'm trying to load some jQuery function, it writes that `jquery is not defined`. I also tried CDN.

````
        <title>
            GRID
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="grid.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
                family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>```
````

Comment: Is `jquery-2.1.1.min.js` the correct URL?  You have it hosted in the same folder as your web page?  Look in your dev tools, you are getting a 404 for that script.

Comment: well did you download/upload the file to that directory?? You have to add the library to the project, it does not just come for free. If you did add it, can you access it directly by typing the path into the address bar?

Comment: Side note: jQuery 2.1.1 is *really* old - released in 2014! It has several known security vulnerabilities - any particular reason this is a requirement? This really should be nowhere near any system in 2019.

Comment: alternatively you can use an external source to load jquery like you do for the fonts

Comment: Can you tell us in which folders are your HTML and your jQuery saved?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for both examples (CDN & local)? What errors (if any) are appearing in your developer console?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `jquery-2.1.1.min.js` file into same location where your quoted file is if we are talking about local purposes.

If your prefer to download it each time, you can use for example Google Hosted Libraries in following way:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: All files are in the same folder.

Comment: Check second possibility with direct url to file hosted by Google.

Comment: I tried all posibilities but nothing works.

Comment: Please attach example of usage.

Comment: I meant, that i tried CDN link but also classic JS file that was downloaded from their official website.

Comment: Show how you are trying to use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Like so `<script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>`, jquery have to be in the root of your domain, like your `script.js`.

If you want CDN, use:

```html
<script rel="prefetch" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js></script>
```

Or official [jQuery CDN](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/):

```html
<script
  rel="prefetch"
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-h0cGsrExGgcZtSZ/fRz4AwV+Nn6Urh/3v3jFRQ0w9dQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Comment: All files are in the same folder, i tried both options but it still writes "VM92:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"